# ¿Tienen idea de porque sale este error? en una consulta de sql serve entre dos schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

No se porque cuando hago un join entre dos esquemas pasa esto.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Final2019.Contactos x
INNER JOIN WS2019.Respuestas z
ON x.UserID = z.UserID
```

> [Err] 22018 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the
>   varchar value '30-44-42' to data type int.

Ambos IDs son int

Comment: porque la columna `UserId` en una tabla es `int` y en la otra es un string

Comment: puedes dar un describe de cada tabla?

Comment: Las tablas no las hice yo, pero tiene razón Lamak, La tabla principal la llave primaria es un string es la primera vez que me topo con esto. En la tabla secundaria la llave foranea si es un int.

Comment: Para corregirlo, puedes convertir la columna int en varchar.

Comment: Mi usuario no tiene permisos para eso. Lo unico que hice fue utilizar la función ISNUMERIC con lo cual los string que no cumplieran la condición eran descartados.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te indica el error es que una de las dos columnas es de un tipo entero (`int` en este caso) y la otra es de tipo cadena de caracteres (`char`, `nchar`, `varchar`, `nvarchar`) y que, al menos para una fila, el motor encuentra un valor que no puede convertir a entero (en tu caso particular el valor `'30-44-42'`).

Esto ocurre debido a la [conversión automática de tipos en SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), que en este caso, convierte la cadena de caracteres a entero y realiza así la comparación.

En mi experiencia, no hay forma de influenciar al motor para que la conversión automática se haga hacia la cadena de caracteres, por lo que lo que queda es, o bien prevenir que se conviertan valores que no son numéricos, o bien realizar una conversión explícita a cadenas de caracteres, utilizando las funciones [`cast` o `convert`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

### Conversión explícita a cadena

- Suponiendo que el campo entero está en la tabla `Final2019.Contactos`, puedes hacer la conversión explícita de manera simple a cadena de esta manera:

  ```
   select *
     from Final2019.Contactos x
          inner join WS2019.Respuestas z ON cast(x.UserID as varchar) = z.UserID
  ```
- Puedes indicar otros tipos, como `nvarchar`, etc.
- Puedes indicar explicitamente la longitud de la cadena a la que deseas convertir.
- Puedes indicar explicitamente el [`collate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) al que quieres que se convierta para la comparación (esto es necesario cuando la columna contra la que vas a comparar tiene un collate distinto del default del motor) por ejemplo:

  ```
   select *
     from Final2019.Contactos x
          inner join WS2019.Respuestas z ON cast(x.UserID as varchar(20)) collate Traditional_Spanish_ci_ai = z.UserID
  ```

Debes tener en cuenta que la comparación de cadenas es más lenta que la comparación de números, aunque su efecto en conjuntos de datos pequeños es imperceptible, si que tendrá un impacto sensible sobre conjuntos de datos grandes, sobre todo si no hay índices que ayuden al motor a optimizar la búsqueda de coincidencias.

### Evitar la comparación de valores que no se pueden convertir a entero:

Puedes *filtrar* con un where los valores que, de antemano, sabes que no se podrán convertir a un entero, para evitar que aparezca el error.

Esta técnica se basa en utilizar la función [`isNumeric`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) para discriminar todos aquellos valores que no pueden convertirse a números, y finalmente utilizar comparaciones de cadena para discriminar aquellos que resulten en números de coma flotante, que también darán error (como `1.25`, para el que `isNumeric` devuelve 1, ya que es número, pero que resultará en el error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.25' to data type int.

Esta es mi opción menos favorita, pues depende de los datos y de tener siempre presente todas las representaciones de cadena que pueden dar como resultado un número de coma flotante, incluyendo si en la cultura el punto decimal se representa por un punto o por una coma.

Una condición bastante completa, sobre un hipotético campo tipo cadena llamado `a.CampoStr`), para este caso, podría ser:

```
 where IsNumeric(a.CampoStr) = 1
   and charindex('.', a.CampoStr) = 0
   and charindex(',', a.CampoStr) = 0
   and charindex('E', a.CampoStr) = 0
   and charindex('e', a.CampoStr) = 0
```

### Conversión explícita a entero

La última, es realizar una conversión explícita a entero, luego de forzar a los valores que puedan ser de coma flotante, a truncar o redondear la parte decimal.

Esta solución depende siempre del uso de `isNumeric`, pero en lugar de *filtrar* los resultados que pueden ser de coma flotante, los trunca o los redondea:

Por ejemplo:

```
select a.campoStr, b.campoInt
  from A 
       inner join B on convert(bigint, floor(a.CampoStr)) = b.CampoInt
 where IsNumeric(a.CampoStr) = 1
   and floor(a.CampoStr) = a.CampoStr
   and floor(a.CampoStr) < 9223372036854775808
   and floor(a.CampoStr) >= -9223372036854775808
;
```

La segunda condición del `where` es necesaria para evitar que nos incluya resultados incongruentes (como que 1.25 es igual a 1).

La tercera y cuarta condición son necesarias para evitar tratar de convertir números que están fuera del rango (en este caso del `bigint`), por ejemplo `1e32`.

De no incluirlo corremos el riesgo de encontrar un valor demasiado grande para convertirlo a un tipo entero, lo que daría como resultado el error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.